# Where is my (gtag) category and label data?

Tags: event-tracking, analytics-events

I’m pushing custom events into Google Analytics 4 with `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={GID}`.

I've checked that my `action`, `category` and `label` variables are generating the strings I need:

```
window.gtag('event', action, {
    'event_category' : category,
    'event_label' : label
});
```

…and my named `action`s *are* landing in my Google Analytics reports, but I can't see any reference anywhere to my `category` or `label` data.

The last time I did something like this was with `ga.js` so although I'm not familiar with the latest Analytics reporting UI with regard to events, I am at least familiar with where and how to go hunting for the category and label data.

My `category` string is a 4 digit integer. My `label` string is stringified JSON, typically of around 250 to 300 characters, so well within the 500 bytes limit of a `label` datum.

But I can't see it. Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: It seems the [answer is probably here](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/79494662?hl=en&msgid=79630263). Apparently in the GA4 UI, one has to turn on `event_category` and `event_label` as explicitly reported custom dimensions. Waiting for results to come back to confirm.